# pip install of statsmodels is not working. DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, numpy, module, statsmodels

I am really new to python and I am trying to install the statsmodels module. It seems that since I am on a 64 bits I need to use the following unofficial website http://www.lfd.uci.edu/ I did all I know about how to download a whl and I did download it and used the pip afterwards and all work fine. now when I do pip install statsmodels it work fine. However, in my shell after I try import the stats models I am getting

```
import statsmodels
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    import statsmodels   File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .tools.sm_exceptions import (ConvergenceWarning, CacheWriteWarning,   File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tools\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .tools import add_constant, categorical   File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tools\tools.py", line 8, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import svdvals   File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\__init__.py", line 174, in <module>
    from .misc import *   File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\misc.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .blas import get_blas_funcs   File "D:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\blas.py", line 155, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import _fblas ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please help me install statsmodels so that I be able to import it

Comment: I ran into something similar a while ago and just switched to winpython  https://winpython.github.io/which works without problems for me  on Windows 7, 8.1 and 10.